# Which is faster inline function or MACRO

Tags: c++, c, performance, function, macros

I believe that preprocessor expands the Macro as a copy text in the code before compilation wherever is it called, while the compiler writes a copy of compiled function definition in each function call. So in both cases we avoided the overhead of regular function call, but in this case which is faster and has less overhead, inline function or MACRO?

Comment: can you show me a difference between both in a preprocessed code?

Comment: example I have MAX (x,y) ( x>y ? x:y) .... int (int x, inty){ return x>y ? x:y;}

Comment: Faster?  You mean to get working?

Comment: Given that a simple macro can take up to 48 hours to get working correctly because macros generate SO 'My macro does not work right' Q&A, the inline code is faster by many powers of 10.

Comment: Profile.  Set optimizations high for speed.  Profile.  Create the build without symbols (a.k.a. release build).  Profile.  Study the assembly language.  How much time did you gain by using macros or inline function?

Comment: In most cases, you will need to gain more than 500 milliseconds in order to make the time negligible.  The time you save by using an inline function (probably nanoseconds maybe a microsecond), is wasted by waiting for I/O or by the operating system swapping out your program (and running another task).  Prefer to spend your time on correctness and robustness.  Most Users hate a fast program that crashes often.  *BTW, 500 ms or 1/2 a second is a fast time between keystrokes.*

Answer (score 2):

The macro will only be 'faster' insofar as it is not left to compiler heuristics whether the macro will be inlined. Given the downsides of macros, it's typically better to leave this decision to the compiler. There are also issues with debugging levels and corresponding source code. Optimization levels, 'forced' inlining, e.g., `__attribute__ ((__always_inline__))` (gcc/clang). More importantly, you avoid common pitfalls such as multiple expression expansion / evaluation within the macro.

I haven't done a S.O. question search (which you should get into the habit of doing), but I suspect this has been answered long before, in much greater detail!

Comment: OTOH, iff the compiler does not inline the function, there might be good reasons not to. It might even speed up the code! And you missed other vital differences. Maybe it really is better to search for a dup

Comment: @Olaf - I have certainly missed other uses. The fact that macros still appear in hight performance code. Like `__asm__` block macros found in Linux and other hight performance software. Non-tail recursive calls cannot be inlined for example. Expensive static functions in a translation unit called by 'light weight' visible functions will bloat code.

Comment: There are other reasons which require macros, especially with Assembler code or template-like code generation. Had this problem e.g. with a breakpoint instruction which required an immediate operand and gcc was not able to pass the inline-argument properly to the `asm` constraint, so the Assembler complained. But most macros are nowadays obsolete and often stem from ppl who just missed/ignored latest advances (including LTO). People asking such question like the one above normally have no need for function-like macros (no offense, just an observation).

Comment: @Olaf - a measure of last resort in modern C/C++ then... but we can't quite get rid of them, like everyone's favourite crazy uncle, `goto` :)

Comment: That's my point. In C less than in C++ (please be careful with the term "C/C++"! It is often missunderstood by beginners and even some self-called professionals). I use them myself to some extend, but cautiously and always well documented why it cannot be an `inline` function.